# What does "sSMTP[2916968]: 501 Mail from address must be same as authorization user" mean?

Tags: email, mail

I tried many many times to send email from command line. But just failed a hundred of times.

I installed mailutils, s-nail, and edit `/etc/s-nail.rc` as

```
set from=xxx@qq.com
set smtp=smtp.qq.com
set smtp-auth-user=xxx@qq.com
set smtp-auth-password=xxxxxxxxxxxx
set smtp-auth=login
```

running

```
echo "test" | mail -s "test" xxx@qq.com
```

gives

```
mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

cat /var/log/mail.log gives

```
Jan 28 12:25:16 aaaa sSMTP[2917096]: Creating SSL connection to host
Jan 28 12:25:16 aaaa sSMTP[2917096]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 
Jan 28 12:25:17 aaaa sSMTP[2917096]: 501 Mail from address must be same as authorization user.
```

What on earth is wrong here? What does it mean by "Mail from address must be same as authorization user"? How to make it work? Thank you so much.

Comment: Reading the message, I would assume that the value you have in `set from` is not the same as what you have in `set smtp-auth-user` 

Comment: @matigo They are exactly the same, I swear

Comment: Then you may want to get in touch with qq.com and ask why you cannot send mail. It's the receiving server that's throwing the error, not the local system. As a final check, have you confirmed that there's no white space after the names? Some mail servers do not trim their inputs ...

Comment: @matigo Oh... I just found an article. I realize I should use `s-nail` instead of `mail` in  `echo "test" | s-nail -s "test" xxx@qq.com`. It finally works!

Comment: Looks like you have solved your issue, congrats! However note that s-nail does need to hand off to an external MTA such as msmtp, ssmtp and friends. If you include the option `set mta=smtps://xxxxx` s-nail will use its own more than adequate mta...

Comment: @andrew.46 Hi, Thank you. But what do you mean by "s-nail will use its own more than adequate mta..."? I do not understand

Comment: You seem to be calling sSMTP from s-nail; this is not necessary as s-nail can send mail by itself

Comment: @andrew.46 I think that is why I failed previously. I call `mail` to send email and look into `/var/log/mail.log`. If I use `s-nail`, `/var/log/mail.log` will have no record.